# Formal approaches to Russian word order

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, word-order

What are the known formal approaches to Russian (or similar languages) word order? I'd expect something expressed in terms of exteded DRT or similar formalism.

Comment: look into hpsg analyses and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Any particular reference you have in mind?

Comment: see the references named on p.25 of [Pzepiorkiwski et al 2007](http://www.seelrc.org/glossos/issues/8/kupsc.pdf)